# How do I find the source of a policy listed in gpresult /z?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I ran `gpresult /z` and found this policy:

```
GPO: Local Group Policy
KeyName:     Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate\DisableWindowsUpdateAccess
Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
State:       Enabled
```

I want to disable that. How do I find the source of this policy and turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the Policy is listed directly after the `GPO:` section.  The listing you provided is set in the machines' local policy, not from a domain defined Group Policy. You should be able to use `gpedit.msc` on the local machine to find/ edit the settings you need.

Comment: I had already tried gpedit.msc -- it showed the policy as disabled. Weirdly, gpresult showed it as enabled. I used gpedit to set it to unconfigured; now it no longer appears in gpresult /z.